# PHP Recoverable fatal error: Method Timber\PostType::__toString() must return a string value

Tags: twig, timber, php-7.4

I've come across this error in my servers `error_log` file that I can't seem to debug due to a lack of a stack trace. I get the following error:

```php
PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Method Timber\PostType::__toString() must return a string value in ... vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code on line 44
```

I have delved into the libraries to try and figure this out, but no such luck, as I am not sure what parts of the Timber library call this method. The code triggering this is, which looks to mean that it should return the slug as a string.

```php
/**
 * Wrapper for the post_type object provided by WordPress
 * @since 1.0.4
*/
class PostType {

    /**
     * @param string $post_type
     */
    public function __construct( $post_type ) {
        $this->slug = $post_type;
        $this->init($post_type);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->slug;
    }
```

Does anyone know of the methods that call this function, as well as a way that I could create a stack trace to work out further problems? (The error line above is the only one I get).

The server is running PHP 7.4, but was likely also appearing under PHP 7.3 as I only did the upgrade to 7.4 recently (within last month) but the error has been in the log since Jan of this year.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `$post_type` you've assigned to the attribute `$slug` is probably an object as well. Force conversion to a string in your `toString` method, e.g,

```php
public function __toString() {
    return $this->slug.'';
}
```

Comment: As this is an external library that I don't control, any amends to the codebase would be overwritten by any composer updates to the [Timber library](https://timber.github.io/docs/). Do you know where this library uses this method?

Comment: Acording to the error, the issue should occur in one of your templates where you do something like `{{ post_type }}`